# React onClick to affect only this iteration

Tags: reactjs, binding, state

I have a page that uses an object that contains lists within lists. I have all the components showing the data correctly, but I'm trying to add a toggle button for each primary list item so you can show/hide their child lists. I had previously made something that would affect EVERY instance of the component when clicked, so when you click the `expand` button it would toggle the child lists of EVERY primary item.

React is new to me and I'm using this project partially as a learning tool. I believe this has to do with binding state to the specific instance of the component, but I'm not sure how or where to do this.

Here is the component:

```
const SummaryItem = props => {
  const summary = props.object;

  return(
    <div className="summary_item">
      {Object.entries(summary).map( item =>
        <div>
          Source: {item[0]} <br />
          Count: {item[1].count} <br />
          <button onClick={/*expand only this SummaryItemList component*/}>expand</button>
          <SummaryItemList list={item[1].items} />
        </div>)
      }
    </div>
  );
}
```

I previously had a state hook that looked like:

```
const [isExpanded, setIsExpanded] = useState(false);
const toggle = () => setIsExpanded(!isExpanded);
```

And in my render function the button had the toggle function in the onClick:
`<button onClick={toggle}>expand</button>` and I had a conditional `if(isExpanded)` with two renders, one with the SummaryItemList component and one without.

Is there a better way to do this besides mapping the object, and how do I bind the state of the toggle to affect only the instance it's supposed to affect?

Comment: As you explained the problem, the button works only for the first time right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you maybe forgot to give each item an isExpanded, the best way to do this is to split up your items and item in different components (in the example below it List for items and Item for item).

```js
const { useState } = React;
const Item = ({ name, items }) => {
  const [isExpanded, setIsExpanded] = useState(false);
  const toggle = () => {
    setIsExpanded((s) => !s);
  };
  return (
    <li>
      {name}
      {items && (
        <React.Fragment>
          <button onClick={toggle}>
            {isExpanded ? '-' : '+'}
          </button>
          {isExpanded && <List data={items} />}
        </React.Fragment>
      )}
    </li>
  );
};

const List = ({ data }) => {
  return !data ? null : (
    <ul>
      {Object.entries(data).map(([key, { items }]) => (
        <Item key={key} items={items} name={key} />
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
};
const App = () => {
  const data = {
    A: {
      items: {
        AA1: { items: { AAA1: {}, AAA2: {} } },
        AA2: { items: { AAA: {} } },
      },
    },
  };
  return <List data={data} />;
};
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks! I was able to copy this right over and make it work without hardly changing anything. A few things that are different about this that I realized I wasn't using was firstly 1. the `key` property for the List component and 2. the bracketed React.Fragment component. I'll have to research that one a bit more. But either way this is a great template for me to work with and learn from.Thank you!